# Current sensor that works in 0nA-250nA range?

Tags: current, current-measurement, photodiode, photosensor

Is there any current sensor capable of sense very low current ranges from 0nA to 250nA?
I would need to sense the current produced by this photodiode: GVGR-S11SD (http://www.geni-uv.com/download/products/GVGR-S11SD.pdf) (http://www.roithner-laser.com/datasheets/pd/uv/gvgr-s11sd.pdf)
Maybe this requires an amp? (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/tech-articles/Optimizing-Precision-Photodiode-Sensor-Circuit-Design-MS-2624.pdf)

[image: Graph]

Comment: What bandwidth is your light signal? What accuracy are you expecting?

Comment: Obviously the answer is "yes" otherwise it's unlikely that this photodiode would exist.  You may, of course, have to design and build your own in order to meet your own requirments.

Comment: Obligatory: https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/test-measurement/article/21766108/whats-all-this-femtoampere-stuff-anyhow from Bob Pease, one of the greats

Comment: @Andyaka The bandwidth is unknown since this is to use with diferent UV leds-drivers combos, but all at +/- 405nm Wavelenght. About accuracy i would like to be the most accurate as possible but most important with good repetition and consistent results, i'm also with 18bit and 24bit ADC.

Comment: I'm not talking about the spectral bandwidth but your signal bandwidth. As "accurate as possible" is NOT helpful. You have to create an error budget for these things. The resolution of your ADC is unimportant. Error budget is what you need to consider. Be scientific or you'll not achieve what you really need to achieve - I can't guess that for you. Signal bandwidth is vital to know.

Comment: @TiagoConceição what andy means is, is this a DC measurement under steady light conditions or is the light changing rapidly. If the light is changing rapidly, and you need the output to faithfully capture that rapid change, then you need to quantify how rapidly it is changing by assigning a frequency to it. Also if DC doesn't matter that would be good to know. If it is AC coupled, then that might relax some specifications.

Comment: "Maybe this requires an amp"  - yes it does. google "photodiode transimpedance amplifier"